# CD crash in 20.04.1

Tags: sound, 20.04, cd

I've moved from 18.04 to 20.04.1 LTS on my desktop. As soon as I insert an audio CD, the whole system (screen and central unit) crash and shut down within a couple of seconds without any prompt, with the CD still inside! On restart, it ends the same way after 4-5 seconds. I managed somehow to exit the CD and Ubuntu starts normally. I tried several CDs, got the same result. Why?
Pentium (R) Dual-Core CPU E5200; Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS 64-bit

EDIT:
If the CD driver is SATA or IDE... how to know? The model is: TSSTcorp CDDVDW SH-224BB (SB00)

```
kam@kam-G41M-Combo:~$ ls -al /var/crash
total 3704
drwxrwsrwt  2 root     whoopsie    4096 nov.  10 09:29 .
drwxr-xr-x 14 root     root        4096 août   5  2019 ..
-rw-r-----  1 gdm      whoopsie 3777065 nov.  10 09:29 _usr_bin_Xwayland.121.crash
-rw-r--r--  1 gdm      whoopsie       0 nov.  10 09:29 _usr_bin_Xwayland.121.upload
-rw-------  1 whoopsie whoopsie      37 nov.  10 09:29 _usr_bin_Xwayland.121.uploaded
kam@kam-G41M-Combo:~$ sudo dmidecode -s bios-version
[sudo] password for kam:
```

FB

MOTHERBOARD: GIGABYTE GA-G41M-Combo S-series

Comment: Is the CD drive SATA or IDE? Edit your question and show me `ls -al /var/crash`, and `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and tell me the EXACT make/model # of your computer or motherboard.

Comment: Regarding your question edits, you can have more information running the following commands: ```
sudo apt install wodim
sudo apt install lsscsi
wodim --devices
lsscsi
``` Reference: https://www.linuxnix.com/find-optical-devicescddvd-roms-details-in-linuxunix/